# Find data in an array and if it matches another array then delete

Tags: php, arrays

I have data that I receive from the database as a string.
I use explode to separate them by character, and I want the data in the array to be compared with the data in another array and if there is a match, then delete

The first argument after explode in the array will be the user's group.
How to navigate by phrase to the first comma to delete data that does not suit me?

Example:

```
$deleteIfFindInArray = ['amazone', 'b2c']

//get data from main array
$tirePriceDataString = $result['tier_prices']; // "b2b,1.0000,1.0900,0,All|amazone,3.0000,1.0600,0,All|b2c,6.0000,0.9900,0,All"

$explodedString = explode('|', $tirePriceDataString);
```

[image]

As you can see on the screen, I have 3 lines, only 1 suits me because amazon and b2c are included in $ deleteIfFindInArray

How do I implement this check and delete?
Return everything to its original position (to a string)?

Comment: Start by studying [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos). Iterate, compare, delete.

Comment: From the looks of it, maybe your database architecture is wrong?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://php/net/array_filter) to remove the lines with the first component in the list using [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array). You could provide the data to the closure using `use ($array)`.

```
$deleteIfFindInArray = ['amazone', 'b2c'];

//get data from main array
$tirePriceDataString = "b2b,1.0000,1.0900,0,All|amazone,3.0000,1.0600,0,All|b2c,6.0000,0.9900,0,All";

$explodedString = explode('|', $tirePriceDataString);

$explodedString = array_filter($explodedString, function($string) use ($deleteIfFindInArray) {
    list($first) = explode(',', $string, 2);
    return !in_array($first, $deleteIfFindInArray);
});

print_r($explodedString);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => b2b,1.0000,1.0900,0,All
)
```